# Upload with Arc.Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm currently creating a small API with Phoenix. Everything is fine except the file upload.

Here is what I get in my logs :

`Parameters: %{"picture_version" => %{"file" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/png", filename: "spectrum.png", path: "/tmp/awea/plug-1456/multipart-745660-733498-2"}, "usage" => "main"}}`

Then an error in the Arc library :

`Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/picture_versions
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        lib/arc/actions/store.ex:39: anonymous fn/1 in Arc.Actions.Store.handle_responses/2
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:704: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.filter/2
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1385: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:704: Enum.filter/2
        lib/arc/actions/store.ex:39: Arc.Actions.Store.handle_responses/2
        lib/arc_ecto/type.ex:5: Arc.Ecto.Type.cast/2
        (ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:590: Ecto.Type.cast/2
        (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:486: Ecto.Changeset.cast_field/6
        (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:418: Ecto.Changeset.do_process_param/8
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1102: Enum."-map_reduce/3-lists^mapfoldl/2-0-"/3
        (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:382: Ecto.Changeset.cast/5
        (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:353: Ecto.Changeset.cast/4
        (copier_creer_web) web/controllers/api/picture_version_controller.ex:10: CopierCreerWeb.API.PictureVersionController.create/2
        (copier_creer_web) web/controllers/api/picture_version_controller.ex:1: CopierCreerWeb.API.PictureVersionController.action/2
        (copier_creer_web) web/controllers/api/picture_version_controller.ex:1: CopierCreerWeb.API.PictureVersionController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (copier_creer_web) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: CopierCreerWeb.Router.dispatch/2
        (copier_creer_web) web/router.ex:1: CopierCreerWeb.Router.do_call/2
        (copier_creer_web) lib/copier_creer_web/endpoint.ex:1: CopierCreerWeb.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (copier_creer_web) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: CopierCreerWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (copier_creer_web) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: CopierCreerWeb.Endpoint.call/2`

I've implemented it by following the readme of both [arc](https://github.com/stavro/arc) and [arc.ecto](https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto). I'm pretty new with Phoenix so I don't totally know what I'm doing ^^

**Edit, controller code**

```
    defmodule CopierCreerWeb.API.PictureVersionController do
      use CopierCreerWeb.Web, :controller

      alias CopierCreerWeb.PictureVersion

      # plug :scrub_params, "picture_version" when action in [:create]

      def create(conn, %{"picture_version" => picture_version_params}) do
        changeset = PictureVersion.changeset(%PictureVersion{}, picture_version_params)

        if changeset.valid? do
          picture_version = Repo.insert!(changeset)

          conn
          |> put_status(:created)
          |> render("show.json", picture_version: picture_version)
        else
          conn
          |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
          |> render(CopierCreerWeb.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
        end
      end

      def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
        picture_version = Repo.get(PictureVersion, id)

        # Here we use delete! (with a bang) because we expect
        # it to always work (and if it does not, it will raise).
        Repo.delete!(picture_version)

        send_resp(conn, :no_content, "")
      end
    end
```

**Edit, uploader config**

```
      defmodule CopierCreerWeb.File do
    use Arc.Definition
    use Arc.Ecto.Definition

    @versions [:original]

    def __storage do Arc.Storage.Local end
  end
```

Comment: Could you add code from you controller?

Comment: @JustMichael I added my controller code

Comment: @JustMichael this controller is inside the same route as my others controller wich accepts only json. But the error does not seems to be related

Comment: @Awea could you please provide your config? (Please don't post your private API keys though.)

Comment: @Gazler there is nothing related to the uploader in my config. I've added the uploader if it's usefulll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests and a fresh new app. It seems that the problem was from Arc 0.4.0 and it's solved in 0.4.1.